# Ionic changing icon color change fails if existing data loads from server

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, icons

Sorry about the subject, not certain how to properly describe this.

I have a rating system for specific content.  The rating page appears in a modal.  The first time the user rates the content, everything works.  If the user doesn't refresh the data from the server, they can go back into the same review/modal and edit their review - including changing the rating which changes the colors of the stars ( 1 thru 5 stars).

But if the user refreshes the data or opens the app for the first time, pulling the data from the server, the modal opens showing all the correct rating and review from their previous entry - but if they want to change the star rating they gave it previously (first rating a `2`, then after fresh server data load, change rating to a `4`), the colors on the stars do not change even though the data recorded from the function shows the value as 4....visually nothing has changed, it still only shows two color'd stars

I am printing out console msgs as it iterates through the star/rating color function, and the console msgs show the correct colors being assigned....but the actual color of the stars do not change.

Relevant CSS:

```
.reviewColor {
  color: lightgray ;
}
```

The modal:

```
<ion-modal-view class="modalReviews">
  <ion-header-bar>
    <div class="headerBar">
      <div class="headerBarDiv">PRODUCT REVIEW</div>
      <button type="button" class="button button-block button-small-custom headerBarButton" ng-click="closeReviews()"> X </button>
    </div>    
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content>
  <div id="reviewWrapper">
    <div ng-if="doReview == 1" id="doReview" class="prodSection prodReviewCard">
      <div ng-if="prod.reviews.userReviewDate != 0">
        Last review submitted on: {{prod.reviews.userReviewDate}}
      </div>
      <div class="" style="text-align:center;">
        <i class="ion-ios-star reviewColor ratingSize" id="Rating_{{prod.ceID}}_1" ng-click="reviewRating('Rating',prod.ceID,1);" ng-style="1 <= prod.reviews.userRating && {'color' : eColors.orange}"></i>
        <i class="ion-ios-star reviewColor ratingSize" id="Rating_{{prod.ceID}}_2" ng-click="reviewRating('Rating',prod.ceID,2);" ng-style="2 <= prod.reviews.userRating && {'color' : eColors.orange}"></i>
        <i class="ion-ios-star reviewColor ratingSize" id="Rating_{{prod.ceID}}_3" ng-click="reviewRating('Rating',prod.ceID,3);" ng-style="3 <= prod.reviews.userRating && {'color' : eColors.orange}"></i>
        <i class="ion-ios-star reviewColor ratingSize" id="Rating_{{prod.ceID}}_4" ng-click="reviewRating('Rating',prod.ceID,4);" ng-style="4 <= prod.reviews.userRating && {'color' : eColors.orange}"></i>
        <i class="ion-ios-star reviewColor ratingSize" id="Rating_{{prod.ceID}}_5" ng-click="reviewRating('Rating',prod.ceID,5);" ng-style="5 <= prod.reviews.userRating && {'color' : eColors.orange}"></i>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px;">
        <textarea style="border:1px solid lightgray;width:100%;height:100px;" maxlength="255" ng-model="userReview" id="userReview">{{prod.reviews.userReview}}</textarea>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:20px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="userAnon" ng-model="userAnon" ng-true-value="'{{userDisplayName}}'" ng-false-value="'Anonymous'" style="margin-left:25px;margin-right:5px;vertical-align:bottom;width:20px;height:20px;" ng-checked="prod.reviews.userAnon != 'Anonymous'"></input>Display '{{userDisplayName}}' with review? 
      </div>

      <div style="margin-top:20px;">
        <button type="button" class="button button-block button-large-custom" ng-click="reviewSubmit();">
          Submit Review
        </button>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:15px;color:{{reviewColor}};">{{reviewMsg}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

The controller function to visually change the star colors:

```
  $scope.reviewRating = function(idName,ID,rating) {
    for (var i=1;i<=5;i++) {
      var tName = idName+ "_" +ID+ "_" +i ;
      console.log(tName) ;
      var star = document.getElementById(tName) ;
      if (i <= rating) {
        console.log("Orange") ;
        star.style.color = eColors.orange + " !important" ;      
      } else {
        console.log("Gray") ;
        star.style.color = "lightgray !important" ;
      }
    }
    $scope.userRating = rating ;
    console.log("new rating: " +$scope.userRating) ;
  }
```

The function console msgs shows the function is executing correctly and the correct value is being assigned as the new $scope.userRating - but again, visually, nothing is changing, its still only showing two stars being colored orange:

```
Rating_1135_1 = Orange    controllers.js:2705 
Rating_1135_2 = Orange    controllers.js:2705 
Rating_1135_3 = Orange    controllers.js:2705 
Rating_1135_4 = Orange    controllers.js:2705 
Rating_1135_5 = Gray      controllers.js:2708 
new rating: 4             controllers.js:2712
```

Again, it only fails to work, fails to change the colors, if a previous review/data is loaded from the server, if one doesn't exist it works just fine, even saving the review, leaving the modal...and coming back later to change the review - it still works.  Its only when the user refreshes the data or gets new data from the server and the review already exists.

Comment: Why are you just AngularJS instead of Angular2? Also please post the code for loading data from server.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you cannot add `!important` when setting a style property (`star.style.color = 'lightgray !important';`).

Ideally you should give it a class instead and give the class style declaration a higher specificity so it will override `.reviewColor` without `!important`.

Another options is to remove the inline `!important` as it's considered bad practice and just set the style without it (which should work as long as you don't have `!important` in another style rule as inline styles have higher priority).

If you really need to set `!important` in the inline style you can use [`element.style.setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) and set the `priority` in the third parameter:

```js
star.style.setProperty('color', 'lightgray', 'important');
```

Comment: I need to add that I only added `!important` when the same code wasn't working.  I added it thinking it would help force the color change, but it too did  not work.  The same issue exists with and without `!important` in the color assignment.  I am wondering if it has something to do the with the `ng-style` applied to each icon.  Going to toy with that today.